# How do I use the cor() function properly?

Tags: r

I keep getting the stupidest error and I can't understand it. I'm working through ISLR (I also don't even know if this is the right thing to do: I don't know Python and I found ISLR does an ok job holding my hand teaching me R) but anyways...

```
library(ISLR, class) 
attach(Auto) 

mpg01 <- ifelse((mpg <= median(mpg)), 0, 1) # Binary variable 
Auto_1 <- c(Auto) 
Auto_1 <- data.frame(Auto, mpg01)
pairs(Auto_1) 
cor(Auto_1)
```

The error I consistently get is:

> Error in cor(Auto_1) : 'x' must be numeric

I have tried "use.complete.obs", na.rm = TRUE... nothing works.

Comment: One of the first things to do when reading data (or loading with `data()`) is to use `str(yourdataframe)` i.e. `str(Auto)`. This will allow you to see the class of the variables. Check this and see if any columns are non numeric. ps I know many intros to R use `attach` but it is best to avoid it as this will save a lot of hassle down the line.

Comment: I'm going to guess that `pairs(Auto_1)` produces "striated" (obvious lines) in the off-diagonal (up-right, low-left) plots, confirming @user20650's suggestion that `Auto$Auto` is either `character` or `factor`. For comparison of known-`factor`, see `pairs(iris[,c(1,5)])` for obvious lines of points, and `cor(iris[,c(1,5)])` for the error and `cor(iris[,c(1,4)])` for what `cor` is supposed to produce.